# CSS : Bad Gray Line to the side of the Navigation Bar on my Website

Tags: html, css

I'm maintaining [the Perl Beginners' Site](http://perl-begin.org/) and used a modified template from Open Source Web Designs. Now, the problem is that I still have an undesired artifact: a gray line on the left side of the main frame, to the left of the navigation menu. Here's [an image](http://www.shlomifish.org/Files/files/images/Computer/Screenshots/perl-begin-bad-artif.png) highlighting the undesired effect.

How can I fix the CSS to remedy this problem?

Comment: You may wish to post the style.css file or a pointer to it.  I think it'll be extremely difficult to answer this question without being able to see your css.

Comment: @Onorio - getfirebug.com

Comment: @yoavf - Thank you! :-)  I didn't know I could do that with Firebug.  Yet another good thing I've learned from SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the `background-image` on the body showing through. Quick fix (edit style.css or add elsewhere):

```
#page-container
{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Would that work since the image is attached to the BODY style?

Comment: Yes, since the #page-container DIV is contained in the BODY. If i understand the author's intentions correctly, the intention was for the image to "leak" around the edges of the container DIV, providing shadows and such. That needs an opaque container to work though.

Answer (score 1):

That is an image. (see it here: http://perl-begin.org/images/background.gif) It's set in the BODY class of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

The grey line is supposed to be there.  The reason why it looks odd is because the very top is hidden by the buffer element.  Remove the `background-color` rule from this ruleset:

```
.buffer {
    float: left; width: 160px; height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255,255,255); 
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt it was intentional. Look at the right edge - it produces a nice drop-shadow effect, as though the page content was a plaque sitting on a white table. Note that the footer also clips this image.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this:

```
#page-container {
    border-left: solid 1px rgb(150,150,150); border-right: solid 1px rgb(150,150,150); 
}
```

However, I'm not seeing why the right border isn't showing up....

Answer (score 0):

I would do a quick fix on this to add the style:

```
border-left:2px solid #BDBDBD;
```

to the .buffer class

```
.buffer {style.css (line 328)
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
   border-left:2px solid #BDBDBD; /* Grey border */
   float:left;
   height:20px;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:160px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem is that you need to set a white background on #page-container. As things stand, it has a transparent background, so the 5pt left margin on navbar-sidebanner is revealing the bg of the page_container ... so change that bg and you're cool.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all the people who answered. The problem was indeed the transparency of the #page-container and the background image of the body. I fixed them both in the stylesheet.